Having a bit of trouble with flex box and tailwind in this example
I have this code working but when I convert some over to tailwind, it breaks and I am not sure why
This works...
<style>
  .box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
</style>

<main class="main">
  <div class="flex w-full flex-auto flex-col box">
  <div class="container flex-auto px-4 py-8 min-h-screen flex flex-col sm:flex-row box">
    <div class="bg-red-400 basis-1/4 box h-64">02</div>
    <div class="bg-green-400 basis-1/4  box h-64">02</div>
  </div>
  </div>

</main>

This does not and I thought it would
<style>
  .box {
    @apply flex align-middle justify-center
  }
</style>

<main class="main">
  <div class="flex w-full flex-auto flex-col box">
  <div class="container flex-auto px-4 py-8 min-h-screen flex flex-col sm:flex-row box">
    <div class="bg-red-400 basis-1/4 box h-64">02</div>
    <div class="bg-green-400 basis-1/4  box h-64">02</div>
  </div>
  </div>

</main>

I did the react starter tutorial to create new project, then did the steps on this page
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation
My changes above are in app.component.html and my index.html looks like this
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>AngularTesting</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="./output.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>

tailwind seems to work as my two div's above go from row based to column when I shrink to mobile size.  I am not sure why @apply doesn't work AND when I move the items into the actual divs, it still has no effect.
Finding and replacing 'box' with 'flex align-middle justify-center' results in 'slightly' better results but still not correct in that the container is left aligned and results are centered in that container.
My endgoal is a responsive page nearly exactly like this one https://www.upwork.com/nx/signup/?dest=home
I tried the stuff I listed above.

Make sure you are placing @apply directive in your .css file as described here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply

make sure your @apply style is in the input file and the following @tailwind are added too :
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

